# How to use the bq ls command line tool to sort by duration

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I get the longest running bq job with the `bq ls` command?

I can't find examples of how to sort results.

EDIT: per comments, it's very confusing to me how to use bigquery logs to see what jobs are running. Take this stackdriver log query, for example:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
logName="projects/my-project/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
protoPayload.resourceName="projects/my-project/jobs/job_abc123"
```

That should return all the logs for job job_abc123, right? Well I only get back one entry with `protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"` and `protoPayload.status` is blank.

So what logs should I search for to see the run history of job_abc123? How do I use BQ SD logs to see in-flight queries and their current run time? Google's docs are confusing and not helpful to me for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to export all your BigQuery logs back to BigQuery itself and then just write some SQL. If you want a hacky/quick solution, you can use some bash magic.

Comment: Is there a way to create a sink to automatically do that? Or do you have to do that manually every time

Comment: No, you'll need to create the sink and write some SQL afterwards. You can save the SQL as a view so you only have to do it once.

Comment: See this link how to automate the log export https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/?utm_source=release-notes&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=2019-december-release-notes-1-en#bigqueryauditmetadata_format. It works very well and you can use a scheduler or any other automate tool to get your longest query

Comment: @TamirKlein but do audit logs show _currently_ running queries? How does that work? Does SD write a log for every minute or something a job is running?

Comment: This is a good question and I believe the answer is yes and the status of the job will   be running. We are using stackdriver and its very powerful tool.

Comment: Updated my question. I dont understand which logs I should be looking at to get the info I want- currently running jobs and their duration. I dont even know how that would work. Like I said SD would need to be pushing a log every X number of seconds/minutes with the current status of every job. Does it do that? If so what log is that?

Answer (score 0):

The bq ls command by itself won't sort by duration or show the longest running job. This would require some extra processing on your end.

Here are some considerations that may be of use:

- Job Duration is only updated when the job completes or fails, thus,
  for running jobs, this field would be empty. An alternative is to
  subtract the Start Time from the current Date Time.
- It would probably be easier to use the BigQuery API [job list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list)
  method instead, since the output is in JSON format, so it should be
  simpler to parse.
- The Stackdriver logs only show the following type of records for
  jobs: Insert Jobs (when the job is created), Job Completed, Get Query
  Results (When the get method is invoked to check the job’s status).
- You may open a feature request for the bq command to enable sorting
  by duration or start time using this [form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685&hl=es-419). But take into account that a
  feature requests is subject to triage and may not be considered in
  the near future's release plans.